# CSS: I can't put a button in the middle of a DIV element

Tags: css, button

I'm using CSS buttons from this tutorial:

http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

I need to put a button in the middle of a DIV so it's centered. But I can't!

Here's the code of the button:

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>Bring world peace</span></a>
```

And here's CSS:

```
.clear { /* generic container (i.e. div) for floating buttons */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

a.button {
    background: transparent url('bg_button_a.gif') no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span {
    background: transparent url('bg_button_span.gif') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
<div align="center"><a class="button" href="#"><span>Bring world peace</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the align attribute for the div element is deprecated. You're better off defining a class for that div, like so:

```
<div class="centerize">
  <a class="button" href="#"><span>Bring world peace</span></a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.centerize { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note however that setting the text-align will only affect the content inside the div. The div itself (should be) a block element, and depending on where it sits in the document structure, may not be centered itself.

Just to make a little more certain, you can do something like this:

```
.centerize {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now you can apply centerize to any element, and that element should take up the entire browser's width and center-align its content.

Comment: Will that work if there are two buttons and we would like to place both on the center?

Comment: I'm surprised; the time it took to ask that question could have been spent trying it out. Here, let me do that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/AUrM8/

Answer (score 4):

Modify the button class for these properties:

```
.button{
  margin-left:50%;
  margin-right:50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

And wrap your link in the div like this:

```
<div align="center">
  <a class="button" href="#"><span>Bring world peace</span></a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works only when there's one word. When there's more than 1 word, I get

BRING
WORLD 
PEACE

Comment: @Alex: Try adding `text-align:center` to both `.button` class as well as the DIV.

Answer (score 3):

The `a.button` is floated to the left. You could try `float: none;` on that element. `margin: 0 auto;` is also useful for center-aligning elements.

Does that help?

Comment: +1. Remove the float from the button. Floated elements are removed from the normal page layout, thus are unaffected by the layout styles of their parent elements.